# Spring Security UserDetailsService must be set Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Just i dont understand, why customUserDetailsService doesn't autowire
There are 2 classes i use

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);
private UserService userService;


@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.getUserBySSO(ssoId);
    log.info("User : {}", user);
    if (user == null) {
        log.info("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
    return new 
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getSsoId(), 
user.getPassword(),
            true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        log.info("UserProfile : {}", role);
        grantedAuthorities.add(new 
SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+role.getRoleName()));
    }
    log.info("authorities : {}", grantedAuthorities);
    return grantedAuthorities;
}

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

=================

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.security")
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("tokenRepositoryDao")
public void setTokenRepository(PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository) {
    this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authentication.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/list")
                .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("pass
word")
            .and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-
me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
            .and()
                .csrf()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices 
persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
    return new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me", 
userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
    return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new 
DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}
}
```

And there is stackTrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserDetailsService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.service.user.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.mightynoobs.springhibernate.service.user.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Please explain me, how it's possible. These classes have the same package, i included this package @ComponentScan annotation. And spring still complains that he cant find @Service Component. There is something easy, but i cant get it. Please help.

Comment: can you show us UserService class ? Is there a Service or Component annotation on this class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't have to mark `customUserDetailService` with `@Service` annotation. Besides, the db operation and transaction shoule be done in userService to distinguish the duty of each layer. Refactor `CustomUserDetailsService` like this:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    // ...

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // the implementation
    }
}
```

And according to Spring Security refence:

> **5.6.5 UserDetailsService**
>
> You can define custom authentication by exposing a custom
>   UserDetailsService as a bean. For example, the following will
>   customize authentication assuming that SpringDataUserDetailsService
>   implements UserDetailsService:
>
> [Note] This is only used if the AuthenticationManagerBuilder has not
>   been populated and no AuthenticationProviderBean is defined.

So remove the bean `DaoAuthenticationProvider` in `SpringSecurityConfig` and:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
    //authentication.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
    return new CustomUserDetailsService();
}
```

Comment: It helped me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The `configureGlobalSecurity` been definition is not guaranteed to be executed after setting the field. Hence the `userDetailsService` is `null`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    authentication.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authentication.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XML config:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="stratusDaoAuthenticationProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="stratusClientUserDetailsService" >
            <security:password-encoder ref="delegatePasswordEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <!-- <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="uriEncodedClientUserDetailsService"/>-->
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: It's better to add some details around your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I faced the same problem

I had the following UserDetails & UserDetailsService

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailImpl implements UserDetails {
   ...
}
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
   ...
}
```

The problem was in the `@Component` annotation
So I just removed it and added the code from the comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773811/14295533)